# Android Grabar Audio via Intent MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION error ActivityNotFoundException No Activity found to handle Intent

Tags: android, android-studio, mediaplayer

Hola mi aplicación tiene 3 botones pero solo me intersan 2: El boton `GRABAR` y `REPRODUCIR` quiero grabar audio mediante Intent y a la hora de grabarlo (boton `GRABAR`) me sale el siguiente error

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND }

y se cae la aplicación pero ya le he agregado un if para que muestre un Toast con el mensaje **No sound record application found**

```
if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
} else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No sound record application found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Porque no se puede grabar via `intent`, via `startActivityForResult` me guie de este [tutorial](https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/kotlinparaandroidya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=28&codigo=76&inicio=15) he probado con el `CODIGO_GRABAR` con los valores de 1 y 50 y nada.

Le he puesto los permisos al manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.provider.MediaStore.RECORD_SOUND" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
```

Este es mi main activity

```
package com.luismiguel.audio

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Intent
import android.media.MediaPlayer
import android.net.Uri
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import java.io.IOException

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener {
    var buttonGrabar: Button ? = null
    var buttonReproducir: Button ? = null
    var buttonReproducirSonido: Button ? = null
    var mp : MediaPlayer ? = null
    val CODIGO_GRABAR = 1
    var uri : Uri? = null
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        buttonGrabar = findViewById(R.id.btnGrabar)
        buttonReproducir = findViewById(R.id.btnReproducir)
        buttonReproducirSonido = findViewById(R.id.btnReproducirSonido)
        buttonGrabar?.setOnClickListener{
            grabar()
        }
        buttonReproducir?.setOnClickListener{
            reproducirGrabacion()
        }

        buttonReproducirSonido?.setOnClickListener{
            sonido()
        }
    }

    fun sonido(){
        val mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.happy).start()
    }

    override fun onPrepared(mp: MediaPlayer?) {
        mp?.start()
    }

    fun grabar(){
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.Audio.Media.RECORD_SOUND_ACTION)
        if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
            startActivityForResult(intent, CODIGO_GRABAR);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No sound record application found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if(requestCode == CODIGO_GRABAR && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK){
            uri = data?.data
        }
    }

    fun reproducirGrabacion(){
        val mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, uri)
        mp.start()
    }
```

Les dejo el [código del proyecto](https://github.com/Miguel546/Audio) y tambien un gif de cuando le doy click al botón grabar me sale el toast.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Que es lo que falla que no me permite grabar audio?

Me ayudan porfavor.

Comment: No entiendo que quieres saber. La respuesta a tu pregunta está escrita en el toast

Comment: Que puedo hacer para intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager() no sea null? Que puedo hacer para que me deje grabar en android.

Comment: descargar una app grabadora de sonido

Comment: Si sería una opción pero quería que alguien me ayude con el codigo que tengo a hacer que se pueda grabar en la aplicacion que les he mostrado en android. ¿Que hay que hacer para que ese código funcione? y grabe.

Comment: El código que muestras no está intentando grabar sonido. Lo que hace es delegar esa tarea a otra app y falla porque no encuentra ninguna.

Comment: Que aplicación debería tener? Yo pensaba que la aplicación llamaba "al grabador que provee el sistema operativo Android" como dice en este tutorial https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/kotlinparaandroidya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=28&codigo=76&inicio=15 entonces este tutorial esta mal?

Comment: Sí, supongo que quiso decir que llama a la aplicación de grabación predeterminada pero no todos los dispositivos tienen una.

Comment: ¿Habrá alguna forma de grabar con mediaplayer como dice en el tutorial?

Comment: Inglés básico: player significa reproductor, grabador se dice recorder. Lo que debes estar buscando es el [MediaRecorder](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediarecorder)